# Comparison of two methods that multiply two sparse matrices (C++)

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am studying the class "SparseMatrix" in the book "Fundamentals of Data Structures in C++" (Horowitz, Sahni, Mehta). While I analyze the Sparsematrix::Multiply() function, I made a new implementation of this method.

Before I describe the new implementation, here is the given header file (SparseMatrix.h):

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef SPARSEMATRIX_H
#define SPARSEMATRIX_H

class MatrixTerm
{ // an entry in a sparse matrix
    friend class SparseMatrix;
private:
    int row, col, value;
};

class SparseMatrix
{//A set of triples, <row, column, value>, where row and column are non-negative
// integers and form a unique combination; value is also an integer.
public:
    SparseMatrix(int r, int c, int t);
    // The constructor function creates a SparseMatrix with
    // r rows, c columns, and a capacity of t nonzero terms.

    int getvalue(int r, int c);
    // atomic getter, use index operator

    void setvalue(int r, int c, int v);
    // atomic setter, use index operator

    SparseMatrix Transpose();
    SparseMatrix FastTranspose();
    // Returns the SparseMatrix obtained by interchanging the row and column
    // value of every triple in *this.

    SparseMatrix Add(SparseMatrix b);
    // If the dimensions of this and b are the same, then the matrix produced by
    // adding corresponding items, namely those with identical row and column
    // values is returned; otherwise, an exception is thrown.

    SparseMatrix Multiply (SparseMatrix b);
    // If the number of columns in this equals the number of rows in b then the
    // matrix d produced by multiplying this and b according to the formula
    // d[i][j] = Σ(a [i][k ] · b [k ][j]), where d[i][j] is the (i, j)th element, is returned.
    // k ranges from 0 to one less than the number of columns in *this;
    // otherwise, an exception is thrown.

    string toString();
    // render a version of the matrix

private:
    int rows, cols, terms, capacity;
    MatrixTerm *smArray;

    void StoreSum(const int sum, const int r, const int c);
    void ChangeSize1D(const int newSize);
};
#endif
```

and this is the given code that have details of the SparseMatrix class (Sparsematrix.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include "SparseMatrix.h"
using namespace std;

SparseMatrix::SparseMatrix(int r, int c, int t)
{
    rows = r;
    cols = c;
    capacity = t;
    terms = 0;
    smArray = new MatrixTerm[t];
    for (int i = 0; i<t; i++) {
        smArray[i].row = r+c;
        smArray[i].col = r+c;
        smArray[i].value = 0;
    }
}

int SparseMatrix::getvalue(int r, int c) {
    // linear search version
    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
        if (smArray[i].row == r)
            if (smArray[i].col == c)
                return smArray[i].value;
    return 0;
}

void SparseMatrix::setvalue(int r, int c, int v) {
    if ((r < 0) || (r >= rows) || (c < 0) || (c >= cols))
        throw "SparseMatrix index is out of bounds";

    int found = 0;
    MatrixTerm move;
    // linear search version
    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
        if ((smArray[i].row == r) && (smArray[i].col == c)) {
            smArray[i].value = v;
            found = 1;
            break;
        }

        if ((smArray[i].row > r) || ((smArray[i].row == r) && (smArray[i].col > c))) {
            if (found == 0) {
                move = smArray[i];
                smArray[i].row = r;
                smArray[i].col = c;
                smArray[i].value = v;
                found = 2;
            }
            else {
                MatrixTerm temp = smArray[i];
                smArray[i] = move;
                move = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    if (found == 1)
        return;
    if (terms == capacity)
        throw "SparseMatrix set exceeds capacity";
    if (found == 0) {
        terms += 1;
        smArray[terms-1].row = r;
        smArray[terms-1].col = c;
        smArray[terms-1].value = v;
    } else if (found == 2) {
        terms += 1;
        smArray[terms-1] = move;
    }
    return;
}


SparseMatrix SparseMatrix::Transpose()
{// Return the transpose of this.
    SparseMatrix b(cols, rows, terms); // capacity of b.smArray is terms
    if (terms > 0) {// nonzero matrix
        int currentB = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < cols ; c++) // transpose by columns
            for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
                // find and move terms in column c
                if (smArray[i].col == c) {
                    b.smArray[currentB].row = c;
                    b.smArray[currentB].col = smArray[i].row;
                    b.smArray[currentB++].value = smArray[i].value;
                    b.terms += 1;
                }
    } // end of if (terms > 0)
    return b;
}

SparseMatrix SparseMatrix::FastTranspose()
{// Return the tanspose of *this in O(terms + cols) time.
    SparseMatrix b(cols, rows, terms);
    if (terms > 0) {// nonzero matrix
        int i;
        int *rowSize = new int[cols];
        int *rowStart = new int[cols];
        // compute rowSize[i] = number of terms in row i of b
        fill(rowSize, rowSize + cols, 0);       // initialize
        for (i=0; i < terms; i++)
            rowSize[smArray[i].col]++;

        // rowStart[i] = starting position of row i in b
        rowStart[0] = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < cols; i++)
            rowStart[i] = rowStart[i-1] + rowSize[i-1];

        for (i = 0; i < terms; i++) {// copy from *this to b
            int j = rowStart[smArray[i].col];
            b.smArray[j].row = smArray[i].col;
            b.smArray[j].col = smArray[i].row;
            b.smArray[j].value = smArray[i].value;
            rowStart[smArray[i].col]++;
            b.terms += 1;
        } // end of for
        delete [] rowSize;
        delete [] rowStart;
    } // end of if
    return b;
}

void SparseMatrix::ChangeSize1D(const int newSize)
{// Change the size of smArray to newSize
    if (newSize < terms)
        throw "New size must be >= number of terms";

    MatrixTerm *temp = new MatrixTerm[newSize]; // new array
    copy(smArray, smArray+terms, temp);
    delete [] smArray;  // deallocate old memeory
    smArray = temp;
    capacity = newSize;
}

void SparseMatrix::StoreSum(const int sum, const int r, const int c)
{// If sum != 0, then it along with it row and column position are
    // stored as the last term in *this.
    if (sum != 0) {
        if (terms == capacity)
            ChangeSize1D(2*capacity); // double size
        smArray[terms].row = r;
        smArray[terms].col = c;
        smArray[terms++].value = sum;
    }
}

SparseMatrix SparseMatrix::Multiply(SparseMatrix b)
{// Return the produce of the sparse matrices *this and b.
    if (cols != b.rows)
        throw "Incompatible matrices for Multiply";

    // A transposed matrix of b
    SparseMatrix bXpose = b.FastTranspose();

    // Returning Sparse Matrix
    SparseMatrix d(rows, b.cols, 0);
    int currRowIndex = 0, currRowBegin = 0, currRowA = smArray[0].row;

    // set boundary conditions
    if (terms == capacity)
        ChangeSize1D(terms+1);
    bXpose.ChangeSize1D(bXpose.terms+1);

    smArray[terms].row = rows;
    bXpose.smArray[b.terms].row = b.cols;
    bXpose.smArray[b.terms].col = -1;

    // Multiplication
    int sum = 0;
    while (currRowIndex < terms)
    {// generate row currentRowA of d
        int currColB = bXpose.smArray[0].row;
        int currColIndex = 0;
        while (currColIndex <= b.terms)
        {// multiply row currRowA of *this by a column currColB of b
            if (smArray[currRowIndex].row != currRowA)
            {// end of row currRowA
                d.StoreSum(sum, currRowA, currColB);
                sum = 0;    // reset sum
                currRowIndex = currRowBegin;
                // advance to next column
                while (bXpose.smArray[currColIndex].row == currColB)
                    currColIndex++;
                currColB = bXpose.smArray[currColIndex].row;
            }
            else if (bXpose.smArray[currColIndex].row != currColB)
            {// end of column currColB of b
                d.StoreSum(sum, currRowA, currColB);
                sum = 0;    // reset sum
                // set to multiply row currRowA with next column
                currRowIndex = currRowBegin;
                currColB = bXpose.smArray[currColIndex].row;
            }
            else if (smArray[currRowIndex].col < bXpose.smArray[currColIndex].col)
                currRowIndex++;     // advance to the next term in row
            else if (smArray[currRowIndex].col == bXpose.smArray[currColIndex].col)
            {// add to sum
                sum += smArray[currRowIndex].value * bXpose.smArray[currColIndex].value;
                currRowIndex++; currColIndex++;
            }
            else
                currColIndex++;     // next term in currColB
        } // end of while (currColIndex <= b.terms)

        while (smArray[currRowIndex].row == currRowA) // advance to next row
            currRowIndex++;
        currRowBegin = currRowIndex;
        currRowA = smArray[currRowIndex].row;
    } // end of while (currRowIndex < terms)

    return d;
}

string SparseMatrix::toString()
{
    string output = "";
    MatrixTerm term;
    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
        MatrixTerm term = smArray[i];
        output += "smArray[" + to_string(term.row) + "][" + to_string(term.col) + "] = ";
        output += to_string(term.value) + "\n";
    }
    return output;
}

SparseMatrix SparseMatrix::Add(SparseMatrix b)
{
    if ((rows != b.rows) || (cols != b.cols))
        throw "Incompatible matrices for Multiply";

    SparseMatrix sum(rows, cols, terms + b.terms);
    int thisIndex = 0, bIndex = 0;
    while ((thisIndex < terms) || (bIndex < b.terms)) {
        int trow, tcol, brow, bcol;
        if (thisIndex < terms) {
            trow = smArray[thisIndex].row;
            tcol = smArray[thisIndex].col;
        }
        else {
            trow = rows;
            tcol = cols;
        }
        if (bIndex < b.terms) {
            brow = b.smArray[bIndex].row;
            bcol = b.smArray[bIndex].col;
        }
        else {
            brow = rows;
            bcol = cols;
        }

        if ((trow == brow) && (tcol == bcol)) {
            sum.setvalue(trow, tcol, smArray[thisIndex].value + b.smArray[bIndex].value);

            thisIndex++; bIndex++;
        } 
        else if (((trow == brow) && (tcol < bcol)) || (trow < brow)) {
            sum.setvalue(trow, tcol, smArray[thisIndex].value);
            thisIndex++;
        }
        else {
            sum.setvalue(brow, bcol, b.smArray[bIndex].value);
            bIndex++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

/*********************************************
void classic(SparseMatrix a, SparseMartix b) {
    SparseMatrix c;
    SparseMatrix bxpose = b.FastTranspose();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < bxpose.rows; j++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a.cols; k++)
                if ((a[i] has index k) && (b[j] has index k))
                    sum += a[i][k] * b[j][k];
            c[i][j] = sum;
        }
}
*********************************************/
```

this is the test code (SparseTest.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SparseMatrix.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int matrix[6][6] = {
            {15,  0,  0, 22,  0,-15},
            { 0, 11,  3,  0,  0,  0},
            { 0,  0,  0, -6,  0,  0},
            { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
            {91,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
            { 0,  0, 28,  0,  0,  0}
    };

    SparseMatrix m(6,6,18);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
                m.setvalue(i, j, matrix[i][j]);
            }

    cout << m.toString() << endl;
    cout << m.FastTranspose().toString() << endl;
    cout << m.Multiply(m.FastTranspose()).toString() << endl;
}
```

and this is the new implementation I made:

```
SparseMatrix SparseMatrix::Multiply(SparseMatrix b)
{// Return the produce of the sparse matrices *this and b.
    if (cols != b.rows)
        throw "Incompatible Matrices for Multiply";

    SparseMatrix result(this->rows, b.cols, this->rows * b.cols);

    SparseMatrix bT = b.FastTranspose();

    for (int i = 0; i < this->terms; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bT.terms; j++) {
            if (this->smArray[i].col == bT.smArray[j].col) {
                result.setvalue(this->smArray[i].row, bT.smArray[j].row, this->smArray[i].value * bT.smArray[j].value);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Does the new implementation perform correctly, just like the original one?
2. If so, I found that the time complexity of the first version is O(a.terms⋅b.cols+a.rows⋅b.terms), and the time complexity of the second version is O(a.terms⋅b.terms), respectively. Is the second versions more efficient than the first one?

Comment: *Does the new implementation perform correctly* -- No.  It has nothing to do with data structures, but C++.  Your `SparseMatrix` is being returned by value in some of your functions, but you have this: `MatrixTerm *smArray;` as a member that handles dynamically allocated memory.  You failed to implement the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for `SparseMatrix`.  Right now, it requires a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.  If you had used `std::vector`, then there wouldn't be this issue.

Comment: It looks like the authors of the original code don't know the first thing about C++.

Comment: This IMO is one of the reasons why using C++ to learn data structures is a double tough job of getting right, unlike if you used another computer language.  There is a lot wrong with your code just in terms of the C++ language, but you wouldn't know it if you followed your data structures book verbatim.   Your code is full of memory leaks, violations of the rule of 3 (already mentioned) and a whole host of other things, and you haven't even gotten to the data structures part of it yet.

Comment: No, your version does not do a matrix multiplication at all.

Comment: @Eugene I added a test code. I ran these codes for many matrices, but I found they run well. Could you tell me why my version is not correct?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your comments. I will be aware of the rule of 3 and other stuffs about C++.

Comment: Apparently, in your examples, the matrices are "too sparse". In a matrix product, each element is a dot product of 2 vectors, i.e., a sum of products of many numbers. In your implementation, each matrix element is just a product of 2 numbers. Try multiplying 2 small matrices that actually have no 0 elements, and you will see the difference.

Comment: @goomseo `iMatrixTerm *smArray;` --> Change this to `std::vector<MatrixTerm> smArray;` and then instead of `smArray = new MatrixTerm[t];` it would be `smArray.resize(t);`.  Then not only are the memory leaks and potential double-frees gone, you now have a better way to check (using at()) if you ever go out-of-bounds.  Otherwise there is no guaranteed way to test your code correctly if you continue using pointers and not implement the rule of 3.

Comment: Oh, and that entire `void SparseMatrix::ChangeSize1D(const int newSize)` becomes `void SparseMatrix::ChangeSize1D(const int newSize) { smArray.resize(newSize); }`.  In addition, there is no need for extraneous member variables that keep track of the size or capacity.  The `vector` has a `size()` member function that tells you how many elements there are.